# Get current class and method?

Tags: php

I'm creating a log function that will log my errors in a file.

I thought it will contain which class and method the error occurred in.

Is there a way of logging in which class and method the error occurred in so I don't have to type it manually each time?

Comment: You might want to provide more information about your logger class and how you intend to call it.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I'm not big on PHP but I believe it has "magic constants" similar to C/C++. Take a look [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php): This seems to indicate you could use

```
__LINE__, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __CLASS__, and __METHOD__
```

Comment: If called in the parent class declaration of a function, this returns the parent, not the extended class

Comment: You can find all the predefined constants here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: @AntonyWoods The link in your answer is dead. Wouldn’t you like to replace it with a link e.g. to the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php)?

Answer (score 44):

In the event you’re in a parent / base class, [`__CLASS__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php#constant.class) will return the parent / base class name which is not desired. In that event you can use [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php):

```
get_class($this)
```

Comment: This does get the child class even if you are in a method defined in the parent.

Answer (score 13):

In current PHP versions (5.5+) you should use `static::class`

It works both in static and instance methods and returns the actual class name, even if the method body was defined in a superclass.

Comment: In PHP 7.1 if the method body was defined in a superclass static::class returns the superclass name

Comment: @g4b0 no, it does not. I just tested this script with PHP 7.1.8: `class A { function f() {return static::class;} } class B extends A {} $b = new B; echo $b->f();` and it correctly prints B, even if the method was defined in A.

Comment: Don't forget about the difference between `self` and `static`. `static` will refer to the class it's called upon while `self` is the class it was created in.

Answer (score 8):

use the `__METHOD__` constant in PHP5

Answer (score 6):

[get_called_class()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) get's the current class. This might also be interesting: [debug_print_backtrace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php).

Comment: You're right, I forgot the context because I've just used it tomorrow. But might be interesting anyway?

Answer (score 5):

In Laravel 5 **CLASS** was returning namespace and class name, so it was a large string. **So this is how you get current Class without all that other stuff**:

```
echo (new \ReflectionClass($this))->getShortName();
```

Comment: This is one of the [slowest methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41264231/4982088) you can use to extract a class short name.

Answer (score 3):

Since **PHP 8.0** there is new way if variable is an object:

```
$object::class

$this::class
```