# finding the name of method i am in

Tags: php, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get current class and method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140282/get-current-class-and-method)

How can i find the name of the method i am using in php? I found how to do this in C but not in PHP. I found a Q on here which roughly talked about magic constants ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140282/get-current-class-and-method)) but I didn't really get it. In the following example I want $thisMethodName to be 'model_databaseLogin'

EG:

```
public function model_databaseLogin()
{
$thisMethodName = ... ;
return $this->model_methodCheck( $thisMethodName );
}
```

Is this possible in php?

Comment: @DragoonWraith: I'm sure there is at least several hundreds of duplicates here ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: quite probably. Feel kinda dumb for answering first and looking second, but then that was probably John's job, not mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer is the magic constants to which you refer; specifically `__FUNCTION__`

These are called "magic" because their value is actually contextually dynamic.

```
public function model_databaseLogin()
{
$thisMethodName = __FUNCTION__;
return $this->model_methodCheck( $thisMethodName );
}
```

There is another way, via debug_backtrace(), but that is decidedly less efficient!

Comment: Thanks, perfect. A lot easier than I thought!

Answer (score 3):

You need the "magic constant" `__METHOD__`. The [magic constant docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) should be helpful.

So your code would be:

```
public function model_databaseLogin() {
    $thisMethodName = __METHOD__;
    return $this->model_methodCheck($thisMethodName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Constants are still pretty new, cheers!