# Get class name of executed static function without namespace

Tags: php

Calling `get_called_class()` in PHP from a static function gives you the class name of the function, including the namespace if called from outside that namespace, it seems.

Is there a way to acquire the class name without the namespace?

(Obviously I understand that it would be possible to examine the string returned by `get_called_class()` and do some hackish stuff, but I am hoping there is a less hackish way to do it)

Comment: Yep, you must to do somethink like this: `array_pop(explode('\\', \App\Vendor\Foo::foo()))`

Comment: @felipsmartins Thank you for the interest in my question, but if you want to try to answer the question, I think SO rules dictate that it should be done in the form of an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Someone alse will copy this sugestion as answer soon... :)

Comment: @felipsmartins I mean no offense, but honestly I do not understand why you think that the fact that you believe someone else will copy your comment into an answer is a proper response to a suggestion that that kind of usage might not be in line with SO rules. I understand that you are trying to help and credit to you for that, but imagine what would happen if everyone posted half-answers with no explanations as to the reasoning behind it in the comments section and expected other people to swoop in and turn it into a real answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Acquiring the class name without a namespace**

Yes, you can do it using the ReflectionClass. Since your question relates to doing this from within a static method, you can get the class name like so:

```
$reflect = new \ReflectionClass(get_called_class());
$reflect->getShortName();
```

This uses the ReflectionClass constructor by passing a string with the fully namespaced name of the class to be inspected.

There is a similar question at [How do I get an object's unqualified (short) class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901850/how-do-i-get-an-objects-unqualified-short-class-name#19909556) however it does not refer to doing this within a static method and so the examples pass an instantiated object to the ReflectionClass constructor.

Comment: Thank you. I accept your answer on the grounds that it's the best solution I know of and it's unhacky enough to not be considered hacky(in my humble opinion).

Comment: Be sure to test how performant this solution is if the called class grows large.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 /**
 * Get the class "basename" of the given object / class.
 *
 * @param  string|object  $class
 * @return string
 */
function class_basename($class)
{
    $class = is_object($class) ? get_class($class) : $class;

    return basename(str_replace('\\', '/', $class));
}
```