# Undefined Type after installing Php Package

Tags: php

I am very new to Php. I am trying to install `kreait/firebase-php` library so I installed composer and I did `composer require kreait/firebase-php`

After that I tried importing the library in one of my php file as follows

```
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
$factory = (new Factory)
    ->withServiceAccount('/path/to/firebase_credentials.json')
    ->withDatabaseUri('https://my-project-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com');
```

but I keep getting
**Undefined type 'Kreait\Firebase\Factory'.intelephense(1009)** in VS Code.

Please, what do I do next?. I am using php 8.0.1

Comment: Please share more details - where do you "get" that?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've forgotten to include Composer's [autoloading mechanism](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading):

```php
require 'path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;

$factory = (new Factory)
    ->withServiceAccount('/path/to/firebase_credentials.json')
    ->withDatabaseUri('https://my-project-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com');
```

There seems to be a common misconception regarding `use`. While it does import an *already loaded* class from its original into the current namespace, so you can reference it by its so-called unqualified instead of by its qualified name (`Factory` vs. `Kreait\Firebase\Factory`, in your case), it doesn't actually import the class from its physical location (i.e., it doesn't deal with the file system) - that's what an autoloader is for:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/66921037/3323348

For the error message you got, cf.:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59266972/3323348